# Content added twice though only looped once

Tags: jquery, ajax, json2html

I want to add more content to my feed making use of AJAX and it does add content - but it adds it twice. To exclude causes like the AJAX request being submitted two times I added the integer `i`. But `i` only equals 1 (as stated by my `h1` element) if I scroll down.

The AJAX `success` function receives a json object (which I can see in the alert) which is then transformed to html twice (the same object and accordingly the same html). Do you have any idea why this problem occurs?

jQuery:

```
function loadMore()
{
    var i = 0;
    var accountpar = $(".parent").length;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'homemore.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'account':accountpar
        },
        success: function(datanew) {
            i++;
            var datarec = datanew.replace(/},]$/,"}]");
            var string  = json2html.transform(datarec,template);
            alert(string);
            $(string).insertAfter($('.parent').last());
        }
    });
    $(window).bind('scroll', bindScroll);
}

function bindScroll(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        loadMore();
    }
}

$(window).scroll(bindScroll);
```

Comment: What happens when you alert the var string? Perhaps it's inserting the string into multiple .parents?

Comment: @JamesG the alert just comes up twice. I think it's because of something with the scrolling... Cause if I'm really careful and scroll down bit by bit the alert is shown only once and thus the content is only added once as well...

Comment: @Moritz you must be binding the scroll event twice. Can you show us the complete code?

Comment: That is the complete code for the jQuery :/

Comment: @Moritz if that is the complete code then when are you binding the scroll event for the first time?? its only inside the loadMore function and no where else.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Reddy sorry, I really missed something I updated the code. :) (see the window scroll down there)

Comment: @Moritz great!! now try this, remove the `unbind` line inside the `bindScroll` function , and also remove the `bind` line of code inside the `loadMore` and try now.

Comment: @Reddy tried that unfortunately didn´t work... :/ thanks though! :]

Comment: @Moritz so you mean you still have the same problem?? :o

Comment: yes, same problem :/ @Reddy

Comment: @Moritz can you create a JS fiddle? to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this. My sense tells me that its' capturing the 'by pixel' and firing more than once. You can download the debounce/throttle plugin and use that, and set it to like 250, or try this "once method"

if using debounce (have to download the plugin)

I re-read your post (after you updated), and you are binding twice:
once like this:

```
$(window).scroll(bindScroll);
```

and again like this:

$(window).bind('scroll', bindScroll);

I feel this is a red flag here. after the re-read, I'd probably either just download the plugin and wrap this in a debounce ($(window).scroll(bindScroll);).

---

```
$.debounce( 250, bindScroll )
```

instead of this:

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', bindScroll);
```

try this:

```
$( window ).one( "scroll", function() {
     bindScroll()
});
```

Comment: oh interesting, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `i++` below like this

```
success: function(datanew) {
        $("h1").text(i);
        var datarec = datanew.replace(/},]$/,"}]");
        //alert(datarec);
        var string  = json2html.transform(datarec,template);
        $(string).insertAfter($('.parent').last());
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Then it just says 0 at h1

Comment: And if I move the h1 under the i++ it still says 1

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
$(string).insertAfter($('.parent').last())
```

Use:

```
$('.parent').append($(string))
```

Comment: Nope, that add 10 more elements if I didn't make a counting mistake.